# Why wont this simple Jakarta Regexp class run?

Tags: java, regex

I am working on a project that requires me to understand the basics of the Apache Jakarta Regexp package for Java. I am somewhat unfamiliar with how to inlcude libraries in a java class. This is what im trying to run:

```
import org.apache.regexp.*;

public class regexpTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RE r = new RE("a*b");
        boolean match =  r.match("aabb");

        if (match){
            System.out.println("yes");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("no");
        }
    }
}
```

I have added Documents\jakarta-regexp-1.5\jakarta-regexp-1.5.jar to my class path, but i get to get it to compile without errors, i have to use:
javac -classpath ...\jakarta-regexp-1.5\jakarta-regexp-1.5.jar regexpTest.java 
that will compile, but when i try to run it like this :
java -classpath ...\jakarta-regexp-1.5\jakarta-regexp-1.5.jar regexpTest

I get an error: "Exception thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: regexpTest"

Any ideas on what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the current directory in your classpath?

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

> The default class path is the current directory. Setting the CLASSPATH variable or using the -classpath command-line option overrides that default, so if you want to include the current directory in the search path, you must include "." in the new settings.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have the current directory in your classpath.  Try this:

```
java -classpath ...\jakarta-regexp-1.5\jakarta-regexp-1.5.jar:. regexpTest
```